# Python how to decode GIS boundary stored as bytes?

Tags: python, byte, gis, openstreetmap, geopandas

I extracted some points of interest from Open Street Map (using the `pyrosm` package) that I later exported to a parquet file. Here are the geometries, which have type `shapely.geometry`:

```
0                                POINT (-82.65865 41.81229)
1                                POINT (-79.03619 43.15180)
2                                POINT (-73.85599 42.61587)
3                                POINT (-73.88552 42.78819)
4                                POINT (-73.97070 40.67335)
                                ...                        
185430    POLYGON ((-77.82350 42.79552, -77.82337 42.796...
185431    MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.82678 42.79437, -77.82673 ...
185432    POLYGON ((-77.82104 42.79403, -77.82091 42.794...
185433    POLYGON ((-77.82415 42.79387, -77.82417 42.793...
185434    POLYGON ((-77.82503 42.79258, -77.82508 42.792...
Name: geometry, Length: 185435, dtype: geometry
```

I write this dataframe to `parquet` with the `to_parquet` method from `pandas`, but upon reading back the df I get the geometries as bytes:

```
0         b"\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@'\xaaT\xc0\...
1         b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0P\xc2S\x...
2         b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xc8vR\x...
3         b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`\xacxR\xc0\...
4         b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 ~R\xc0\...
                                ...                        
185430    b'\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00...
185431    b'\x01\x06\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03...
185432    b'\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00+\x00\x0...
185433    b'\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00...
185434    b'\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x0...
Name: geometry, Length: 185435, dtype: object
```

It seems that the `pyarrow`/`fastparquet` engines have trouble writing the geometries.

I've made a few attempts at conversion, using the below string as a sample:

```
x = b"\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x8bp\x93Q\xe5\xb5S\xc0\xc5\x98\xaaj8\x80E@\xe4\x8a\xe6\\\xe5\xb5S\xc0\x84\xe3\xe8\xe0O\x80E@\xeb\xa9\xd5W\xd7\xb5S\xc0\x84\xe3\xe8\xe0O\x80E@\xc2\xff\xb1k\xd6\xb5S\xc0\xce\xefE\xc5I\x80E@i\xe5^`\xd6\xb5S\xc0'\xbc\x04\xa7>\x80E@\xeb\xa9\xd5W\xd7\xb5S\xc0\x19i\xf3I8\x80E@\x8bp\x93Q\xe5\xb5S\xc0\xc5\x98\xaaj8\x80E@"
```

Attempt 1:

```
str(x,'utf-8')
```

Attempt 1 Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-e93cefe956dd> in <module>
----> 1 str(test,'utf-8')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 13: invalid start byte
```

Attempt 2:

```
x.encode('utf-8').strip()
```

Attempt 2 Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-44a32c3005da> in <module>
----> 1 test.encode('utf-8').strip()

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I've also tried using Python's `geojson` package but `geojson.Polygon(x)` returns an array of ints:

```
{"coordinates": [1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 139, 112, 147, 81, 229, 181, 83, 192, 197, 152, 170, 106, 56, 128, 69, 64, 228, 138, 230, 92, 229, 181, 83, 192, 132, 227, 232, 224, 79, 128, 69, 64, 235, 169, 213, 87, 215, 181, 83, 192, 132, 227, 232, 224, 79, 128, 69, 64, 194, 255, 177, 107, 214, 181, 83, 192, 206, 239, 69, 197, 73, 128, 69, 64, 105, 229, 94, 96, 214, 181, 83, 192, 39, 188, 4, 167, 62, 128, 69, 64, 235, 169, 213, 87, 215, 181, 83, 192, 25, 105, 243, 73, 56, 128, 69, 64, 139, 112, 147, 81, 229, 181, 83, 192, 197, 152, 170, 106, 56, 128, 69, 64], "type": "Polygon"}
```

Is there a different decoder that I could use? **How can I decode the above byte string?**

*Update:*

Converting the df to a `GeoPandas` df and using its `to_parquet` method worked. It'd still be nice to know how to make the conversion without using `GeoPandas`.

Comment: Please provide more detail on exactly how and where you got the byte string you posted.

Comment: @Woodford thanks updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format seems to be WKB, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry

There are many packages that can decode it, but it is geometry-specific binary format, so you would need to use some geometry-specific package like geopndas or parse_wkb to decode it.

Comment: wow first time I've ever heard of WKB (as opposed to WKT). thanks for the clarity (using `wkb.loads(x)` from `from shapely import wkb` did the trick)